# Dojo Tabpanel in OneUI 3 sometimes does not render

Tags: dojo, xpages, tabcontainer

Do you guys have trouble in loading/rendering the Dojo TabContainer with OneUI 3/OneUINext within an XPage and Chrome, too?
I experience issues when I load a page which contains the Dojo Tabpanel from the Extlib within the Extlib WidgetContainer. When I reload the page everything is ok but loaded directly from a link of the application layout control it sometimes does not render. There is only one partial refresh on the page then I press a button (save the document). No problems in Firefox and IE so far but only Chrome.

Did I miss something? What are your settings on that DojoTabcontainer control? Let me know :)

Thank you in advance!

FYI: I use jQuery in my pages (just loading the libs, not rendering anything here).

```
<xe:djTabContainer id="djTabContainer1"
                tabPosition="top" tabStrip="true" persist="false" doLayout="false"
                defaultTabContent="djTabPane1">
                <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane1" title="Anzeige"
                    closable="false">
```

...

And so on.

Comment: Remove the jQuery and test again. My hunch: that's the issue.

Comment: Changed to the tabbedpanel control now and everything works fine. Thanks for answering though :)